# What's up with the strange characters in some display names?

Tags: discussion, users

I assume it's not just me: Why have some users added special characters to their usernames? The list includes:

- Kit (now [KitΘδς](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8360/kit))
- z7sg (now [z7sg Ѫ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5964/z7sg))
- JSBangs (now [JSBᾶngs](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/48/jsbngs))
- Martha (now [Marthaª](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1547/martha))
- aedia (now [aedia λ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8732/aedia))
- Alain Pannetier (now [Alain Pannetier Φ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5432/alain-pannetier))
- RegDwight ♦ (now [RegDwight Ѭſ道 ♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwight))
- Matt Ellen (now [Matt Эллен](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3559/matt-ellen))
- Mr. Shiny and New (now [Mr. Shiny and New 安宇](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/380/mr-shiny-and-new))
- Robusto (now [Robusto 初夢](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto))
- Bogdan Lataianu (now [Bogdan Lătăianu](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5249/bogdan-ltianu))
- rumtscho (now [румчо](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4252/))

(OK, me too... drm65 turned into [drɱ65 δ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/dr65))

Comment: And what letter is that: z7sg Ѫ

Comment: @GEdgar:  If you use Firefox, the addon "Character Identifier" lets you highlight text and get Unicode data about the characters. Ѫ happens to be U+46A, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER BIG YUS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a [chat thang](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95/2011/8/4/12-14). Various theories abound about how it started:

- It's all Alain Pannetier Φ's fault
- But since he added his Φ in direct imitation of the CHAOS team's Ψ, it's really all Joel's fault
- We're just χάοτικ by nature
- It's to celebrate EL&U's birthday

Note that there was argument about how the trend started all of 5 seconds after it started, so you will probably never get a definitive answer.

Comment: Also: I don't know if Bogdan really counts as an instance of this trend, since *Lătăianu* is how his name is actually spelled in proper Romanian orthography.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs, except his handle used to be spelled *Lataianu*, and now it's spelled *Lătăianu*. So he changed it to go along with this trend, same as the rest of us.

Comment: Though now he's Theta30... things get confusing sometimes. :6

Answer (score 9):

It's a new trend: To be cool, you need to have at least a greek letter in your username. Just don't use *Ψ*, if you are not part of the CHAOS project.

In the case of RegDwight, as he is moderator, the diamond (*♦*) is used to show he is a moderator; it's not a character he added to his username.

Comment: What about you?  And ª isn't a greek letter.

Comment: I have never said to be cool. `;-)` Plus, my username is in Esperanto; I should eventually use Esperanto characters, but those in _kiamlaluno_ are the same used in the English alphabet.

Comment: Shouldn't CHAOS be *χ*, or would that not be chaotic enough?

Comment: @Peter Shor The _Ψ_ is more mystical, as it seems a candelabrum.