# Why the Greek letters in usernames?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's up with the strange characters in some display names?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/whats-up-with-the-strange-characters-in-some-display-names)

I noticed this trend of late: users appending Greek letters to their usernames. Why or when did this suddenly become popular? A very curious trend.